# read a csv file in sql query with header and other option in delta live table( not in streaming) in databricks without unsin live streaming

Tags: csv, azure-sql-database, databricks

had a issue can a read a csv file in sql query with header in option without using autoloader (streaming) or python syntax.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could try some of the code examples on this page. If you get it working please decsribe in an answer https://sqlrelease.com/skip-header-and-footer-rows-in-hive

Comment: Also please do not paste pictures, paste code instead as it is searchable

Comment: thats what i did  << create or refresh live table ${mypipeline.bronze_table}
as select * from csv.`${mypipeline.InputStorage}/UnitsConversionsReference.csv` >>

Comment: there is a format for creating delta live table its not like our useal sql << AS SELECT * FROM LIVE.*** (or csv."url", parquet."url")  >>

Comment: Did you try `TBLPROPERTIES('skip.header.line.count'='1')` as mentioned in the link i pasted? Please edit your question and replace the picture with text

Comment: yes but i get this error <org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
mismatched input ''skip.header.line.count'' expecting {'APPLY', 'CALLED', 'CHANGES',.......
== SQL ==
create or refresh live table units_bronze

as select * from csv.`wasbs://units@******dataraw.blob.core.windows.net/UnitsConversionsReference.csv`
TBLPROPERTIES('skip.header.line.count'='1')
--------------^^^>